# Selecting variable by name

Tags: vb.net, structure

I'm not sure of the appropriate search term so please close and point me to a duplicate if that's the case.

I have a structure with has multiple variables. I've created an array of the type of the structure. I've added data to a few indexes of the array. I now want to select the a specific variable based on the name of the variable.

He's an example of the structure:

```
structure struc
dim name as string
dim lvl as integer
dim capacity as integer
end structure
```

And the deceleration of the array:

```
dim vills(3) as struc
```

Comment: A dictionary with the key based on the name field would be simpler

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I ideally don't want to change the structure because I already have a fair amount of code working with it as is. I'm hoping for a cleaver work around to be able to access any of the variables by name. :)

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg do you want to select the particular struc from that array based on values of a particular variable in that struc?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I have a string with either "Name", "lvl" or "capacity" in it. I want to be able to select the appropriate variable based on this string. So if the string says "lvl" then I can get the integer value of the lvl variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tony Hopkinson mentioned, it is possible via Reflection:

```
Public Class Form1

    Structure struc
        Dim name As String
        Dim lvl As Integer
        Dim capacity As Integer
    End Structure

    Dim vills(3) As struc

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i As Integer = 0 To vills.Length - 1
            vills(i).lvl = i * 10
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim fi As Reflection.FieldInfo
        Dim fieldName As String = "lvl"
        For i As Integer = 0 To vills.Length - 1
            fi = vills(i).GetType.GetField(fieldName, Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
            If Not IsNothing(fi) Then
                Dim value As Object = fi.GetValue(vills(i))
                Debug.Print(i & ": " & value.ToString)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Up to you to decide if it's worth it...

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You should be using public *fields*, not variables</strike> Actually you have the terminology correct according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/18ytyskd.aspx), the only thing you are missing is the access modifier i.e.

```
Public Structure Struc
    Public Name As String
    Public Lvl As Integer
    Public Capacity As Integer
End Structure
```

At the moment your variables are private which means they aren't accessible from outside your `Structure`.

---

Looking at your comments it looks like you are trying to access the property by name *dynamically* rather than knowing it at compile time. There are a few ways of doing this, most of which involve some [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173183.aspx).

You should perhaps have a look at [ExpandObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - it's effectively a key/value dictionary with the characteristics of a normal class-type object so you get the best of both worlds e.g.

```
Dim struct As Object = New ExpandoObject()
struct.name = "SomeValue"
struct.lvl = 3
struct.capacity = 100
Console.WriteLine(struct["name"])
Console.WriteLine(struct["lvl"])
```

Comment: So after making this change how would I be able to select the variable by name?

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg yes you would be able to do, for example, `myStructure.Name` or `myStructure.Lvl` etc.

Comment: So I'm able to use myStructure.("Name")?

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg no you don't need the `("Name")` part, the fields are accessibly directly by name as per the example above. See [Structure Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/18ytyskd.aspx)

Comment: You are going to have to use reflection to do it that way, which is why @Steve suggested using a dictionary.

Comment: Time to make a decision basically, are you going to take the hit in speed and complexity and Find a member of the struct by it's member name, or are you going to rework your existing code to always access members with myStructure["Name"]. Happens to us all mate.

Comment: Difficult decision really. I was hoping to use something like: for each member of struct... and then if member name = "lvl"... etc. So how would I go about using a dictionary? I'll start reading msdn on it. :D

Answer (score 1):

I really think that if this is an important and frequent requirement (find an element by key) then you should think twice and change your array to a Dictionary(Of string, struc) and use something like this

```
Dim vills = new Dictionary(of String, struc)
Dim s = new struc() 
s.name="k1"
s.lvl=1
s.capacity=1
z.Add(s.name, s)
....
struc c = vills("k1")
if(c IsNot Nothing) Then
    Console.WriteLine(c.lvl.ToString())
End If
```

but if you still want to use an array you could search your struc array by name using Linq

```
Structure struc
    Public Dim name as string
    Public Dim lvl as integer
    Public Dim capacity as integer
End Structure

Sub Main
    Dim vills(3) as struc
    ....

    Dim c as struc = wills.Where(Function(x) (x.name="keyName")).Single()
    if(c.name IsNot Nothing) then
        Console.WriteLine("Found")
    End If
End Sub
```